# escaping special characters in url from typescript call to reach mvc controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, url, escaping

I have an asp.net mvc controller :

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        GET("{name:alpha}")]
        public ActionResult Build(string name)
        {
            var model = new MyModel(name)
            return View("model);
        }
    }
```

And the following typescript code, that takes an user input and called the previous controller by adding the user input at the end:

```
    function callUserInput(userinput)
    {
        mycall(`./Website/Home/Build/${userinput}`)
    }
```

This is working well when the user gives an input containing no special characters, for example if he gives "myname", my Build method is called, but if he gives
an input containing special characters (whitespace, -, _), like "my_name", "my-name", "my name", my Build method is not called and he gets a 404 not found.

I have tried to escape the mycall parameter like this :

```
    mycall(encodeURIComponent(`./Website/Home/Build/${userinput}`))
```

but it changes nothing, I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

`escape()` will not encode: @*/+

`encodeURI()` will not encode: ~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'

`encodeURIComponent()` will not encode: ~!*()'

Try `escape() or encodeURI()`

if it didnt work. then try

```
encodeURIComponent( `./Website/Home/Build/${userinput} `).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, "%2A")
```